# Python struct.pack() 'struct.error: bad char in struct format' when trying to save endianess

Tags: python, struct

I am trying to pack a string and the length of a string.

```
fmt = '<P' + str(len(string)) + 'p'
```

This leads me to an error : struct.error: bad char in struct format
Whereas, doing

```
fmt = 'P' + str(len(string))+'p'
```

Does not give me an error. I am unable to understand why this happens, my understanding is that specifying '<' at the start will make it little endian regardless of the native machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `struct` module docstring:

```
The remaining chars indicate types of args and must match exactly;
...
Special case (only available in native format):
  P:an integer type that is wide enough to hold a pointer.
```

So you can't modify the endianess when you use the `P` format; it is only available in native format.

See also Note 5 here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters

Comment: Missed this in the docs :(. I guess I will use long long instead of a Pointer, I just wanted a large unsigned integer to specify my length of string.

Answer (score 1):

"<" does pack the data as little endian, but it does so by using the "Standard" alignment, not the machine's native rules of the computer. You can see the table at [the struct module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct-alignment).

As pointed out by Warren Weckesser, the P format can't have its endianess modified, but if you use "<i" instead, for example, that will completely work.