# Loading dict to binary - bad char in struct format

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, struct

I have an incredibly large dict of the shape:

```
{'rounding': (4, [(900, 1), (4406, 0), (5772, 1), (6210, 1)]), 'thee': (5, [(901, 1), (3452, 1), (3803, 1), (4178, 1), (5793, 1)]), 'hotdog': (13, [(902, 2), (902, 2), (996, 1), (1765, 1), (2602, 1), (3824, 1), (4701, 1), (4924, 1), (5544, 1), (5741, 1), (5984, 1), (6972, 1), (7236, 2), (7236, 2), (7469, 1)]), 'hotdogs': (9, [(902, 1), (1765, 2), (1765, 2), (4924, 0), (5110, 1), (5228, 1), (6883, 1), (7034, 1), (7236, 1), (8638, 1)]),}
```

It continues on and on for about ~450k terms or so. It is a very large dict. I need to write this object to a binary file. I am following these resources:

- [Python struct.error: bad char in struct format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49670627/python-struct-error-bad-char-in-struct-format)
- [Python struct.pack() 'struct.error: bad char in struct format' when trying to save endianess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960877/python-struct-pack-struct-error-bad-char-in-struct-format-when-trying-to-sa)
- [struct.error: bad char in struct format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996458/struct-error-bad-char-in-struct-format)

The code that is resulting in an error is (the whole program is a few thousand lines):

```
inverted_index = {word:(document_frequency[word], d[word]) for word in d}
json_dict = json.dumps(inverted_index)
struct.pack(json_dict)
```

Which yields the error

```
  File "take_7.py", line 179, in <module>
    main()
  File "take_7.py", line 176, in main
    driver(sys.argv[1])
  File "take_7.py", line 164, in driver
    struct.pack('i', json_dict)
struct.error: bad char in struct format
```

I tried looking up [struct documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) and then tried:

```
inverted_index = {word:(document_frequency[word], d[word]) for word in d}
json_dict = json.dumps(inverted_index)
binary_file = struct.pack('s', bytes(json_dict, 'utf-8'))
```

Which compiled. However:

```
print(binary_file) yields b'{'
```

And

```
print(struct.unpack('s', binary_file)) yields (b'{',)
```

**How can I convert my `dict` (as described above) to a binary file, so that I can save it to disk, and later read it back from disk to be used?**

Comment: `dumps` produces a large string (unicode in Py3).  `struct.pack` with 's' is for **1** byte character.  Why do you need a binary file?

Comment: I also tried using `p` but that still didn't work.

Comment: You are entirely misunderstanding what `struct` does - it only handles data of a fixed structure (which you must completely describe via the format string), and produces output of a fixed size.  The JSON string is *exactly* what you want to write to a file, and easily read back in - "binary" offers you absolutely no benefits here.

Comment: The requirement is somewhat vague -- just that this `inverted_index` dict structure must be written `as a binary file` to disk (and `subsequently read back in as a binary file`). Saving as a `.json` does not meet that requirement. Looking through https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html I did not see any options for dict, so I tried following the examples others had posted.

Comment: Well, you could use `pickle` instead of `json`, and get a file that technically fulfills this arbitrary requirement.  The disadvantage is that you can no longer simply *look at the file contents* to see what's in it, `pickle` is not human-readable at all.

Comment: Cannot use `pickle`, and it needs to be read back in. I have also examined `bytes` and `to_bytes` I think? But could not figure out how to implement.

Comment: I give up, then,  I could suggest other reasonable solutions, but your actual requirements seem to be summed up as "no reasonable solutions allowed".

Comment: Do you consider "write a dict to binary without using pickle that can be read back from disk" as unreasonable?

Comment: You could pack your data, e.g. `packed = zlib.compress(json.dumps(inverted_index).encode('utf-8'))`, and write to a file in binary mode.

Comment: I've never heard of `zlib` - can you post example?

Comment: I can't, as the question has been marked as duplicate. [zlib](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/zlib.html) is part of the standard library. It allows to compress bytes objects, and is not related to the core of your question (i.e. serialization of data structures).

Comment: Another problem is that `json.dumps` converts tuples to lists, so after subsequent `json.loads`, you will have a dictionary that is not equal to the original one.

Comment: I have another similar question, if you'd like to post there? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57981513/how-to-convert-unicode-to-4-bit-binary-representation/57982155?noredirect=1#comment102373517_57982155