# How to convert unicode to 4 bit binary representation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, format

I have the following functions:

```
def dict_to_binary(the_dict):
    json_dict = json.dumps(the_dict)
    binary = ' '.join(format(ord(letter), 'b') for letter in json_dict)
    return binary

def binary_to_dict(the_binary):
    jsn = ''.join(chr(int(x, 2)) for x in the_binary.split())
    d = json.loads(jsn)  
    return d
```

These functions take in a dict object, cast it to json, and then use `ord` to get the unicode for each item in the `json` and then convert that to binary.

How can I edit that `format` string to do this for 4-bit binary representation, instead of the 8-bit it is currently representing? Full code below:

```
inverted_index = {word:(document_frequency[word], d[word]) for word in d}

thebinary = dict_to_binary(inverted_index)
print(thebinary)
print()
print()
print()
convertedbinary = binary_to_dict(thebinary)
print(convertedbinary)
```

Yields

```
1111011 100010 1101100 1101111 1110010 1100101 1101101 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110001 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1101001 1110000 1110011 1110101 1101101 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110001 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100100 1101111 1101100 1101111 1110010 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110010 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110001 101100 100000 110001 1011101 101100 100000 1011011 110011 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1110011 1101001 1110100 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110001 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100001 1101101 1100101 1110100 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110001 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100011 1101111 1101110 1110011 1100101 1100011 1110100 1100101 1110100 1110101 1110010 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100001 1100100 1101001 1110000 1101001 1110011 1100011 1101001 1101110 1100111 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100101 1101100 1101001 1110100 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1110011 1100101 1100100 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100101 1101001 1110101 1110011 1101101 1101111 1100100 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1110100 1100101 1101101 1110000 1101111 1110010 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1101001 1101110 1100011 1101001 1100100 1101001 1100100 1110101 1101110 1110100 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1110101 1110100 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110011 1011101 101100 100000 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110011 1011101 101100 100000 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110011 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1101100 1100001 1100010 1101111 1110010 1100101 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100101 1110100 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100100 1101111 1101100 1101111 1110010 1100101 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110010 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 101100 100000 1011011 110011 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1101101 1100001 1100111 1101110 1100001 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100001 1101100 1101001 1110001 1110101 1100001 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100101 1101110 1101001 1101101 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100001 1100100 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1101101 1101001 1101110 1101001 1101101 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1110110 1100101 1101110 1101001 1100001 1101101 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1110001 1110101 1101001 1110011 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1101110 1101111 1110011 1110100 1110010 1110101 1100100 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100101 1111000 1100101 1110010 1100011 1101001 1110100 1100001 1110100 1101001 1101111 1101110 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1110101 1101100 1101100 1100001 1101101 1100011 1101111 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1101100 1100001 1100010 1101111 1110010 1101001 1110011 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1101110 1101001 1110011 1101001 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100001 1101100 1101001 1110001 1110101 1101001 1110000 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100101 1111000 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100101 1100001 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100011 1101111 1101101 1101101 1101111 1100100 1101111 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100011 1101111 1101110 1110011 1100101 1110001 1110101 1100001 1110100 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110010 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100100 1110101 1101001 1110011 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110011 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100001 1110101 1110100 1100101 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110011 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1101001 1110010 1110101 1110010 1100101 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110011 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1110010 1100101 1110000 1110010 1100101 1101000 1100101 1101110 1100100 1100101 1110010 1101001 1110100 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110011 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1110110 1101111 1101100 1110101 1110000 1110100 1100001 1110100 1100101 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110011 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1110110 1100101 1101100 1101001 1110100 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110011 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100101 1110011 1110011 1100101 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110011 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100011 1101001 1101100 1101100 1110101 1101101 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110011 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100101 1110101 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110011 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100110 1110101 1100111 1101001 1100001 1110100 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110011 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1101110 1110101 1101100 1101100 1100001 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110011 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1110000 1100001 1110010 1101001 1100001 1110100 1110101 1110010 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110011 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100101 1111000 1100011 1100101 1110000 1110100 1100101 1110101 1110010 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110100 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1110011 1101001 1101110 1110100 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110100 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1101111 1100011 1100011 1100001 1100101 1100011 1100001 1110100 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110100 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100011 1110101 1110000 1101001 1100100 1100001 1110100 1100001 1110100 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110100 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1101110 1101111 1101110 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110100 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1110000 1110010 1101111 1101001 1100100 1100101 1101110 1110100 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110100 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1110011 1110101 1101110 1110100 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110100 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100011 1110101 1101100 1110000 1100001 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110100 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1110001 1110101 1101001 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110100 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1101111 1100110 1100110 1101001 1100011 1101001 1100001 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110100 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100100 1100101 1110011 1100101 1110010 1110101 1101110 1110100 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110100 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1101101 1101111 1101100 1101100 1101001 1110100 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110100 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100001 1101110 1101001 1101101 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110100 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1101001 1100100 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110100 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1100101 1110011 1110100 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110100 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 101100 100000 100010 1101100 1100001 1100010 1101111 1110010 1110101 1101101 100010 111010 100000 1011011 110001 101100 100000 1011011 1011011 110100 101100 100000 110001 1011101 1011101 1011101 1111101



{'lorem': [1, [[1, 1]]], 'ipsum': [1, [[1, 1]]], 'dolor': [2, [[1, 1], [3, 1]]], 'sit': [1, [[1, 1]]], 'amet': [1, [[1, 1]]], 'consectetur': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'adipiscing': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'elit': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'sed': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'eiusmod': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'tempor': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'incididunt': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'ut': [1, [[2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3]]], 'labore': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'et': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'dolore': [2, [[2, 1], [3, 1]]], 'magna': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'aliqua': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'enim': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'ad': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'minim': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'veniam': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'quis': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'nostrud': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'exercitation': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'ullamco': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'laboris': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'nisi': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'aliquip': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'ex': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'ea': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'commodo': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'consequat': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'duis': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'aute': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'irure': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'reprehenderit': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'voluptate': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'velit': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'esse': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'cillum': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'eu': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'fugiat': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'nulla': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'pariatur': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'excepteur': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'sint': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'occaecat': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'cupidatat': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'non': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'proident': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'sunt': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'culpa': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'qui': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'officia': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'deserunt': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'mollit': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'anim': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'id': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'est': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'laborum': [1, [[4, 1]]]}
```

Comment: Your 6-bit are mostly 7-bit and represent 8-bit without leading `0`.

Comment: Good to know, I didn't catch that. I will edit the question. Do you know how I can change the `.format` to make them 4 bit?

Comment: How would a 4-bit representation of a 7+-bit number look like? Give some examples!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [[Python 3.Docs]: base64 — Base16, Base32, Base64, Base85 Data Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#module-base64) (*b16encode* and *b16decode* in particular, to convert the string to *char*s that fit in 4 *bit*s) combined with some string <=> *int* conversions:

> ```py
> >>> import base64
> >>> import json
> >>>
> >>> d0 = {'lorem': [1, [[1, 1]]], 'ipsum': [1, [[1, 1]]], 'dolor': [2, [[1, 1], [3, 1]]], 'sit': [1, [[1, 1]]], 'amet': [1, [[1, 1]]], 'consectetur': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'adipiscing': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'elit': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'sed': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'eiusmod': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'tempor': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'incididunt': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'ut': [1, [[2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3]]], 'labore': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'et': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'dolore': [2, [[2, 1], [3, 1]]], 'magna': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'aliqua': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'enim': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'ad': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'minim': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'veniam': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'quis': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'nostrud': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'exercitation': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'ullamco': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'laboris': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'nisi': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'aliquip': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'ex': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'ea': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'commodo': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'consequat': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'duis': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'aute': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'irure': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'reprehenderit': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'voluptate': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'velit': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'esse': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'cillum': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'eu': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'fugiat': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'nulla': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'pariatur': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'excepteur': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'sint': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'occaecat': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'cupidatat': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'non': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'proident': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'sunt': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'culpa': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'qui': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'officia': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'deserunt': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'mollit': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'anim': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'id': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'est': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'laborum': [1, [[4, 1]]]}
> >>>
> >>> b16enc0 = base64.b16encode(json.dumps(d0).encode())  # Convert the string to bytes using utf8 (default)
> >>> b16enc0
> b'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'
> >>>
> >>> bits = " ".join("{0:04b}".format(int(chr(c), 16)) for c in b16enc0)
> >>> len(bits)
> 15369
> >>> bits[:0x9f]  # Print first 32 binary groups (as the whole thing is too long)
> '0111 1011 0010 0010 0110 1100 0110 1111 0111 0010 0110 0101 0110 1101 0010 0010 0011 1010 0010 0000 0101 1011 0011 0001 0010 1100 0010 0000 0101 1011 0101 1011'
> >>>
> >>> # Now, the reverse
> ...
> >>> b16enc1 = "".join("{0:X}".format(int(i, 2)) for i in bits.split())
> >>> d1 = json.loads(base64.b16decode(b16enc1))
> >>>
> >>> d1
> {'lorem': [1, [[1, 1]]], 'ipsum': [1, [[1, 1]]], 'dolor': [2, [[1, 1], [3, 1]]], 'sit': [1, [[1, 1]]], 'amet': [1, [[1, 1]]], 'consectetur': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'adipiscing': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'elit': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'sed': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'eiusmod': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'tempor': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'incididunt': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'ut': [1, [[2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3]]], 'labore': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'et': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'dolore': [2, [[2, 1], [3, 1]]], 'magna': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'aliqua': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'enim': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'ad': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'minim': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'veniam': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'quis': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'nostrud': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'exercitation': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'ullamco': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'laboris': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'nisi': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'aliquip': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'ex': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'ea': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'commodo': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'consequat': [1, [[2, 1]]], 'duis': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'aute': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'irure': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'reprehenderit': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'voluptate': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'velit': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'esse': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'cillum': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'eu': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'fugiat': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'nulla': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'pariatur': [1, [[3, 1]]], 'excepteur': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'sint': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'occaecat': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'cupidatat': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'non': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'proident': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'sunt': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'culpa': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'qui': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'officia': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'deserunt': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'mollit': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'anim': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'id': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'est': [1, [[4, 1]]], 'laborum': [1, [[4, 1]]]}
> >>>
> >>> d1 == d0
> True
> ```

I didn't encapsulated them in functions, that's trivial.

Comment: The line `bits[:0x9f]`, what exactly does that do, and why do I not write `bits = bits[:0x9f]`

Comment: No, it just prints some data (as the whole string is too long).

Comment: What if I just to not `" ".join` and instead have one long bitstream, how could I read that back in?

Comment: That's not a bitstream, it's a sequence of strings, actually it's a generator. Then you den't need to do the opposite step(`.split()`).